# How is it that underground nuclear tests create huge caverns without violating conservation of mass?

Tags: nuclear-physics, conservation-laws, earth, explosions

[If a multi-megaton underground nuclear test 500m down in deep hard rock detonates, we’re told that it will leave a rather radioactive cavern in its wake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Gnome_(nuclear_test)) <sub>(I’m just using Gnome as an example, I’m not asking about Gnome specifically)</sub>.

…but you can’t just make rock *disappear*? That mass has to go somewhere. I know it’s *necessarily* going to turn into molten rock at some point, but that is not a compressible fluid, and eventually it would have to expand when it cools.

So how is there a cavern?

Comment: The rock doesn’t disappear… it merely changes form. I’m not even sure how this is a question.

Comment: From your Gnome link " For this reason, it was decided that Gnome would be detonated in bedded rock salt. The plan was to then pipe water through the molten salt ". salt melts in water and can flow away.

Comment: @MattHanson:  It sounds like the OP agrees with you.  I'm also curious about the cavern.  After cooling off, would we have a spherical cavern surrounded by some denser form of rock?  Or would we have something more like a hemisphere with resolidified molten rock underneath?

Comment: If you are really interested about the cavities  in underground explosions here is a link https://www.osti.gov/biblio/1762870 .

Comment: "How is there a cavern?" is a reasonable question. Can a bomb really push 500 meters of rock up far enough to create a cavern? Does rock have preexisting pores or cavities? Was rock compressed so that it takes up less volume? None of these sound like obviously correct explanations. How did it happen? The report anna linked briefly mentions alterations to rock, but not in much detail. In some cases chimneys do extent to the surface. But not in others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the bomb goes off underground, the surrounding rock gets fractured and the fireball pushes the rock away in all directions. That rock mass does not disappear; it is displaced through a significant distance and in response the surface of the surrounding ground rises slightly by an amount equal to the cavern volume. The cavern can persist if its walls are strong enough but if close enough to the ground surface, the cavern will collapse, leaving a circular crater behind. The Nevada test site is pockmarked with hundreds of such craters.

Comment: Well, hundreds... If you get a morning flight from Phoenix to Portland OR or Seattle WA you can get a nice view of the NTS out the right side of the aircraft often. Lots of circular shadows.

Comment: @JonCuster, I have a book called How To Photograph An Atomic Bomb which contains an aerial photo of one piece of  the nevada test site with lots of craters- but no sense of how many craters there actually were at the site, hence the qualification. Will edit. -NN

Comment: https://www.osti.gov/opennet/manhattan-project-history/publications/DOENuclearTests.pdf is a good reference.